# How do you filter text in Kdevelop?

Tags: kate

In Kate, I can highlight a block of text, invoke the ad-hoc filter functionality with a key binding and then enter an arbitrary command into the dialog box. (Most of the time, it's a variation of `sort` or `grep` or `perltidy`.) The block is fed into the command's stdin, and when the command is done, its stdout text replaces the block.

How do you do that in Kdevelop? There is no text filter menu entry or key binding.

Comment: I have only used KDevelop once and that sometimes ago, but the answer seems contained in this [blog entry](http://milianw.de/blog/kdevelop-externalscript-plugin) from 2010, saying that you should use the ExternalScript plugin. If that post from 2010 is still correct, you should have that plugin and an example in the distribution for doing `sort / uniq` on the selection in the current document. The text also seems to say that Kate Scripts are supported.

Comment: Please comment on our ideas.

Comment: There's nothing to comment, [thomas](https://superuser.com/u/762942) showed that the text filter plug-in does not even exist.

Comment: Did you check if the ExternalScript plugin and examples exist in your distribution? You could also remark on the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that `textfilterplugin.so` is a `KTextEditor/Plugin` which resides in `/usr/lib/qt/plugins/ktexteditor/`. Kdevelop plugins are stored in `/usr/lib/qt/plugins/kdevplatform/` and have to be `KDevelop/Plugin`.

So you need to fork `textfilter` and make a Kdevelop plugin out of it. Here is your starting point:
https://github.com/KDE/kate/tree/master/addons/textfilter

EDIT:

As [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) pointed out: there exists quite similar plugin for KDevelop called [`externalscript`](https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/tree/master/plugins/externalscript). If activated you can configure it with the help of the docked panel to the right called "External Scripts". With this you can configure a script to be called "filter text", bind it to the keys you are used to and let it execute something like `sh -c 'cmd=$(Xdialog --title "Command?" --inputbox "Please specify command to execute:" 10 100); [ -x "$cmd" ] && "$cmd"'`.

I couldn't test this solution because the plugin is unable to run any executable for me (using KDevelop 5.2.1). Not even the buildin sort is working on my installation. But maybe it works for you. You may need to install `Xdialog`.

Comment: This variation works for me (whitespace handling in shell is tricky): `sh -c 'eval $(kdialog --title "Text filter" --inputbox "Filter command:")'`

Answer (score 0):

KDevelop uses Kate as its text editor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337804/mutil-line-editing-in-kdevelop

And also you might want to take a look at the key-bindings listed here for what you are looking for: https://kate-editor.org/kate-vi-mode/